# XCode Compiling LessCSS in Build Script Fails

Tags: xcode, node.js, build, less, xcode4.3

After upgrading to Node.js 0.6.14 (from 0.4.11), I'm suddenly unable to compile less in my XCode build script. (XCode is version 4.3.2).

The error I am getting is:
`Env: node: No such file or directory`

I'm using the following command: `lessc "$PROJECT_DIR/www/css/style.less" > "$PROJECT_DIR/www/css/style.css"`

This works perfectly fine from the command line (I've even tested with the `echo`ed output for "$PROJECT_DIR/www/css/style.less" and it works fine with 'rm').

xcrun is able to find lessc as well:

```
xcrun -find lessc/usr/local/bin/lessc
/usr/local/bin/lessc
```

Any possible idea as to what could be causing this problem?

Edit: Adding: `PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin` to the build script seems to fix the problem, although I'm still curious why XCode isn't using my $PATH variable.

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932424/where-is-path-set-in-xcode