# Mogenerator not found by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcdatamodel, mogenerator

I'm trying to use Mogenerator in my iOS project developed in Xcode 5. I've installed Mogenerator with brew:

```
brew install mogenerator
```

then link:

```
brew link mogenerator
```

After that I have access to this tool from my command line.

Next I'm trying to add one more step (script executing) in build phases (shell /bin/sh):

```
mogenerator --model "${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProject/Model.xcdatamodeld/Model.xcdatamodel" --output-dir "${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProject" --template-var arc=true
```

In effect I get error:

```
line 2: mogenerator: command not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

Do you have any advices how can resolve this issue?

Comment: Where is mogenerator installed? What does `type mogenerator` on the command line show?

Comment: mogenerator is /usr/local/bin/mogenerator

Comment: The path to the model file was not correct. This was my case. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If /usr/local/bin is not in the search path used by Xcode, you can call mogenerator 
with an absolute (full) path:

```
/usr/local/bin/mogenerator --model ...
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, if I specify full path then everything works properly. Do you know how can I add /usr/local/bin/ path to by used by Xcode?

Comment: @Grzegorz: I don't know. It seems that Xcode has a hard-coded search path. If you inspect the build logs, you will see something like `setenv PATH "...:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`. I have no idea if or how that can be modified.

Comment: @Grzegorz: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932424/where-is-path-set-in-xcode. It seems that you can set a custom path by creating a file `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` (but I did not try it yet).