# XCode doesn't recognize environment variables

Tags: xcode, bash, environment-variables, xcconfig

I use the following script to run XCode (7.0.1 7A1001) on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5:

```
export FOO=bar #this should not be necessary, but just in case
launchctl setenv FOO bar #should make it visible to all GUI applications (=XCode)
open -a xcode
```

I then open a workspace with two projects: *App1* and *App2*. In both projects I put `$(HOME)/$(FOO)` in the *Header Search Paths* field.

- In *App1* it is resolved to `/Users/ohads/bar` as expected.
- In *App2* it is resolved to `/Users/ohads/` - note how the `HOME` variable is resolved, but the `FOO` variable is not.

What's going on here? Why the discrepancy? How can I make `FOO` work in App2 - is there some special flag or declaration I'm missing?

BTW, as if that's not weird enough, App1 works even when I only use `export` (as opposed to `launchctl` which is what one should use for GUI applications, seeing as `export` should only affect cash applications).

Comment: Hi! What version of OSX you are using?

Comment: @Arseniy added to question

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `FOO` defined somewhere in the App2 settings ?

Comment: `launchctl setenv` should work, however I don't see why you cannot use paths relative to the Xcode project and just ensure the Xcode project is in the right place?  Using an environment variable in this way, actually makes your process harder.

Comment: Pretty sure, because in my actual case FOO is dependent on the current directory, and I can see the change reflected when I open XCode from a different folder.

Comment: @trojanfoe we are using xcconfig files that are common to many projects so that won't work. And even if it did, I'm not going to change our entire build configuration at this point (I wasn't the one who created it, FWIW). Besides, like you said `launchctl` should have worked, so what am I missing?

Comment: Well that's fair enough.

Comment: The `export` should be sufficient, since `open -a xcode` opens the GUI app from within a `bash` session. GUI apps that are opened from the Finder, which is not started from a `bash` session, are the ones who need `launchctl`. (Unless `open` does not fork/exec the process, instead sending a message to the OS to open the app, in which case this comment is irrelevant.)

Comment: @chepner thanks for clarifying, but regardless, it doesn't work. However I believe I did find the solution, will add an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this has to do with [new XCode 7 behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite). In order for XCode to use environment variables the following command must be issued:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode UseSanitizedBuildSystemEnvironment -bool NO
```

Once this command is issued, both `export` and `launchctl` work (as per chepner's comment). I can only guess it was working in *App1* because it was created in an older XCode version.