# How to read a custom environment variable in a run script, Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, shell

I have a run script in my Xcode project's Build Phases. I want to make it run only on machines where a custom environment variable is set.

In my `~/.bash_profile` file I have

```
export MY_VARIABLE="TRUE"
```

There is an appropriate check in the Xcode's run script:

```
if [ "$MY_VARIABLE" != "TRUE" ]; then
    exit
fi
```

I tested this code in Terminal, and it works well, but Xcode's run script does not see `$MY_VARIABLE`.

Does anybody know how to make it visible in the run script?

I tried the approach recommended in this answer but it does not work for me:
[XCode doesn't recognize environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235958/xcode-doesnt-recognize-environment-variables)

Thank you!

Comment: Apps don't see the environment variables you set in your profile.  See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications) on SuperUser.

Comment: Why don't you set a custom userdefined setting? It will be only for your account and your machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add `source ~/.bash_profile` to begin of your run script.

Comment: Thank you @Thanh Vu, it works! I did it previously in my Terminal and restarted Xcode thinking that it should work. Passing it right to the script made it work.