# OS X GUI Cocoa app interacting with shell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, shell, terminal

Background:

We are developing an in house use only cocoa app to help us with some basic sysadmin tasks and complex website deployments. This application is basically a wrapper around many different bash shell commands. The output from these commands will sometimes need to parsed or displayed to the user.

We have played around with NSTask and are able to launch some scripts. However, this seems somewhat cumbersome (needing to set the exact path, passing in each argument separately, etc...). We can use NSTask in this way if this is actually the preferred method.

The biggest challenge so far is setting up the shell environment. We interact with many ruby gems and programs and deploy using capistrano.

The Question is:

How can we interact with the shell with an environment setup like a user? (aliases, rvm, ruby, paths)

Comment: is your "cocoa app" a GUI app (with buttons and windows and bells & whistles) or is it a tool called from the shell displayed via Terminal.app ?

Comment: Yes it is a GUI app - I have updated the question title to reflect this

Comment: So far you have three "close this question" votes (not from me, though), although I think the people voting to close aren't looking carefully at your question:  it ***is*** a programming question you're asking.  I might answer it myself later on today if nobody else does, but I think it would require a bit of research to see what environment variables are picked up automatically by NSTask or even calls to "`system( )`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variables you'll see set in your shell in Terminal.app are pretty much confined to whatever shell you're using in the Terminal context.  It's not picked up by "`NSTask`" automagically.

But... you do have options. [Some of them are described in answers to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386783/nstask-not-picking-up-path-from-the-users-environment).

You can set more universal environment variables that *do* get picked up by NSTask via the "`~/.launchd.conf`" file, or you can set the shell of "`NSTask`" to match the one in Terminal (which means you pick up .bashrc or .profile or whatever initializes paths) via "[`[NSTask setLaunchPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTask/setLaunchPath:)" (where the launch path is your shell).

And of course you can also call "[`system()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/system.3.html)" from within your tools. This may also pick up the variables set in the "`~/.launchd.conf`" file.

[More information on environment variables is available in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Perfect! You pointed me to a solution that works well for me... via `[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];`