# Different $PATH from Console and Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash, cocoa, environment-variables

OK, I must be missing something very simple but here's what:

- If I `echo $PATH` in the terminal, I'm getting `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/drkameleon` which is correct
- Now if I run an `NSTask` and try executing a simple bash script (`/usr/bin/env bash myscript.sh`) to echo `$PATH`, it prints `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

(I've even tried with `getenv`, or print the entire `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment]` dictionary, but the `PATH` variable is simply... wrong)

What's going on? How can I have access to the *real* `$PATH` as seen in the terminal?

Comment: What happens if you try `bash -l` to make it run like a login shell? The contents of `$PATH` is often modified in a `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Take a look at answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386783/nstask-not-picking-up-path-from-the-users-environment , you will find your answer there

Comment: @LevLandau I discovered it almost the very same time you posted your comment. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When executing a command via NSTask, not your bash, zshell or whatever kind of shell you are using, is started. Hence the PATH (and other environment variables) are different from your environment variables when echoing them in the terminal.

*Reason:* NSTask uses `fork()` and `exec()` for command execution.

IMHO, there are two possible solutions for the problem.

**1. You could set the wanted PATH via the `setEnvironment:`method of NSTask**

Here is some untested example code, which should do the trick:

```
NSTask *task = //Configure your task
NSDictionary* env = [task environment];
NSString* currentPATH = env["PATH"];
NSString* yourPathExtension = @"/your/path";
env["PATH"] = (currentPATH != nil) ? [yourPath stringByAppendingFormat:@":%@", currentPATH] : yourPathExtension;
[task setEnvironment:env];
```

This adds `:<old-PATH>` after the current PATH from NSTask.

**2. You could start `/bin/bash` within NSTask**

```
task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-l",
                 @"-c",
                 @"<your command here>",
                 nil];
[task setArguments: args];
```

This task will start /bin/bash with the PATH configured via `~/.bashrc` etc. and execute the command within the bash.

*Pro:* Your command has all the usual environment variables of your bash

*Con:* You rely on the users PATH variable which can be quite different from yours which may lead to unexpected behavior.

Which solution is the best one for you depends on your use case. In your provided example, both approaches should work fine.

In general, according to the NSTask and NSProcessInfo documentation, the environment variables are equal to the variables of the process from which the application has been started. Hence you might solve your problem when starting your application from the bash.

Comment: I've already solved the issue. But this answer is simply awesome - and great reference for people dealing with the same issue. So, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: NSTask probably uses posix_spawn() nowadays instead of fork()/exec().